# Hostility, deleted rude comment, and personal attack by downvoting of old question

Tags: support, deleted-comments, downvote-reason, rude-or-abusive

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [OpenOffice Calc find value in table, return value of other cell in same row as match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56732212/openoffice-calc-find-value-in-table-return-value-of-other-cell-in-same-row-as-m)

I believe my post here was specific enough before the edits, and yet the situation began with one user posting a respectful comment, and me not understanding the reason for said comment. Immediately after, he became arrogant, rude, and hostile, insulting my competence in an elitist fashion, and after replying to that comment, identifying exactly how he was rude and insulting, all at once, both our comments were removed, my question was flagged as "too broad", and received downvotes to this question, and one other question I posted in 2012.

I respectfully request a review of this situation and would appreciate any respectful help.

Thank you.

Comment: Well, one of the users literally has the word "downvoter" in the name, for one. And I am hopeful the review would at least reveal unfairness and reversal of unwarranted downvotes/flagging

Comment: there's literally nothing we can do that you can't. cast a mod flag.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know you can just flag it for moderation. Thanks, Kevin.

Comment: If someone was called "the upvoter" would you have any issue? likely not? don't fret it.... at least not that part of the exchange. Stick to the facts: It was closed as "too broad". Why do you think it's not too broad? Leave the names of the users who closed out of it. Focus on actions, not on ppl :)

Comment: Aww man, came too late. Comments already looked to be cleaned.

Comment: @Patrice funny, E_net used to have "E_net is kind and welcoming" for their username.

Comment: @Davy yeah I remember. I don't think it would have changed much of the exchange here...

Comment: Well, Patrice, I never said I have an issue with the name, just that it's more than a coincidence, especially with the timing.

And yes, Mysticial, I discovered this meta after it happened. Now I know for next time

Comment: @daddy If you don't have issues with the name, my main suggestion is : remove that piece from your question. It detracts from the issue :) .  As for the "is it too broad"... I would say so. You are basically asking "I wanna do all of this to my sheet. What do now?" Would be better if you had tried to do something, had some code, then you come with "I have this code, which should do X, cause of these docs. However I get Y. Can I get some help in fixing my code to do X?"

Comment: @Patrice You have been more helpful with your main suggestion than anything that happened in my actual question. Thank you, Patrice.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I checked that post, and think this is different enough (not being a flood detectable by the algorithm) to warrant a separate post

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ if that's frowned upon, I won't do it again.

Comment: @daddy7860 Rather than complaining about downvotes and throwing out personal insults, rude and insulting behavior, and blaming everyone else, why don't you try *fixing the problems with your question*, so that it will actually merit upvotes, instead of downvotes.

Comment: @Servy you know, I thought I already did that, but apparently nobody told me until now the question is still for some reason too broad, after I included an example code and even more specific goals for my question. I have seen much more vague questions on the OpenOffice forum, so I'll just go there.

Comment: Treat people the way you want to be treated. Including those who (you think) are being rude to you. Being rude right back never solved anything.

Comment: @daddy7860 Editing your question to just assert that it's not too broad, insult people for closing it as such, repeatedly, and to add *even more things you want to do to your question* isn't making it *less* broad.  The single most effective way you can ruin any possible chance you have of getting help salvaging your question or getting it answered is to go around constantly insulting people for trying to help you fix it, time and again.

Comment: @KevinB no matter how pissed I can ever get, literally nothing I can say to that truth

Comment: @Daddy7860 You cannot claim that apparently nobody told you, because 5 users told you by closing the question, which puts a banner saying "Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question. If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit the question." Patrice's helpful comment basically was just repeating the "Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once." part.

Comment: As one of the close voters, when your question was originally closed it was easily too broad, you'd made no attempt and just given a list of criteria for the thing that you wanted, we won't write code for you. Now that it's been edited, I'm honestly not interested in even looking at it to review whether or not it warrants reopening purely based on your responses here (and on the question) today. As for *"I have seen much more vague questions on the OpenOffice forum, so I'll just go there"* - Feel free, you may have better luck there. (and FWIW, I didn't even downvote your question.)

Comment: @DavyM I see, so my understanding of clear and the help centre are not aligned. I will check those rules now

Comment: @NickA Thank you for the honesty, Nick. I just thought my attempt wasn't worth posting, since it didn't work in the slightest. It also makes sense you won't just write code for me. I'd also like to ask why my responses here today cause you not to even want to look at it

Comment: Have I just been mentioned around here?

Comment: @daddy7860 An attempt is *always* worth posting, regardless of how bad you consider it to be, people value effort, if they think you've made no effort why would they help? As for why I won't look, I've seen the edits you made to the post ("too much hostility", "ganged up on", "without anyone telling me the problem"), you were explicitly told the problem in the close banner (as mention above), you were in no way ganged up on (lots of peoples questions get closed, some get downvoted into the ground, closing is just one way we moderate content, we don't do it as an insult or an attack).

Comment: You need to understand that we get dozens (hundreds even) of *awful* questions every day, we can't walk everyone through writing their questions because we don't have the time. I can't comment on your competence being insulted or elitism because I can't see the comments that were deleted, but your list of issues mentioned here appear as a "woe is me, reopen my question". We won't reopen your question based on what has happened to you, we'll reopen it based on the merits of the question itself, but moaning doesn't encourage others to help. (This isn't an attack, just harsh truth)

Comment: @NickA I don't see it as an attack. You're taking extra time to explain something to me despite your negative opinion of my actions. Thank you for all this information and your time. I will value these suggestions.

Comment: In case any of you folks are wondering about my display name, have a look at the second paragraph of my biography. Although it has a bit of a "bait-y" touch, it has the serious purpose of sending a message: to not be afraid to downvote where it's due. It does not mean to mindlessly downvote everything. Being a downvoter does not make me a rude person, in fact, being a downvoter should **never** equate to being grumpy or hostile.

Comment: Adding up to what the answers say: even if you think that you were personally attacked, replying back with a similar tone is _never_ the right option. Next time, just flag the comment and move on. The [be nice policy](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) applies to everyone, after all.

Comment: I just reviewed it. The only rude comment there was from you, where you called someone who was making a suggestion to post an image a “dick”. So yeah, that has now been deleted. Downvoting is not a rude or unfriendly activity. We can disagree about your question being good quality, but still be friends. Speaking of your question, it is off-topic for Stack Overflow, as it is not programming related. Questions about using consumer software packages like OpenOffice can be directed to [SU].

Comment: @CodyGray so snarky remarks and sarcasm don't count as rude comments; only insults do? Also I've rewritten my question and title, but am still getting downvoted. Am I doing anything else wrong, here?

Comment: When a moderator says that the other comments were merely suggesting to improve your question, it usually means that they weren't snarky or sarcarstic enough to merit an unfriendly/unkind flag. A pro tip here is to assume good intentions first (and preferably _always_), and look beyond the tone of the comment, since that is often misinterpreted online.

Comment: The commenter was expressing their reservations about downloading a file from some unknown person on the Internet, especially considering it was a spreadsheet document that could contain malicious macros. We could argue about their phrasing. They were perhaps somewhat dismissive, but I personally think that’s reasonable, considering the inherent risks involved in what you were asking them to do and how it flies in the face of long-standing site policy. You were the one asking for help; they were trying to help you help yourself. Hard to see how that’s rude. It was in *no way* a personal attack

Comment: I’d guess the question on main is still getting downvoted because people believe it is off-topic or otherwise unsuitable for Stack Overflow. I tried to convey that sentiment in my original comment. This Meta question is being downvoted because people disagree with you, and because it seems a lot like a rant.

Comment: @CodyGray Well, thank you for the insights. I've looked at the "how to ask" and done what I can, so now it's not worth my time to continue trying on this site. I didn't realize it's so strict here.

Comment: @daddy fair, Stack is not for all, that's for sure. But the reason for the strictness is to retain the very experts that make it so most Google queries will lead you back here. It's a bit of a double edged sword.... And the site doesn't do a great job of putting that context in place I think.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe your question basically boils down to "How can I iterate through a sheet, and when a certain value is found, return other values from the same row?" That question though is surrounded by a lot of stuff that's kind of hard to parse:

> I'm trying to search through a table from another sheet, find multiple identical text values in that table, and for each match, return from that table several non-adjacent cells to place into adjacent cells in the current sheet.

This is a reasonable background to what you're doing, so it's a decent start.

> Sheet 2 has a table with num, start, end, and a title of "X" Sheet 1 has a table with many columns (not in order) including num, start, end, and title (which may contain "X")

Here, you're providing a lot of specific information about your environment, and this is one of the issues with your question. If all you're looking for is how to lookup the "X" on one sheet and copy values from the same row, specifying all these other fields for the people reading your question (num, start, end, title) doesn't actually help them answer the question. Additionally, I think you're missing some punctuation, as the sentence as a whole doesn't really make sense. It sounds like you're saying the columns may be in any order on different rows, but the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKspk.png) shows columns named "num," etc, always in the same place.

This paragraph would probably have made more sense if it said "On one sheet, I have all the information, including a title column labeling each row. The other sheets have a title which needs to match the title of the first sheet, and if it matches, I need to copy some of the other columns. "

> How can I iterate through Sheet 1.title, and when "X" is found, return the values of num, start, and end from the same row as the match for every match it finds (with no duplicates)?

Here you're asking multiple things:

1. How can I iterate through Sheet 1.title
2. How can I tell when "X" is found
3. How can I return the values of multiple columns from the row I matched
4. How can I eliminate duplicates?

That's the core as to why this question is too broad: You're asking multiple things at once. Likewise, it would have been valid to go for "Unclear what you are asking" based on the second paragraph and the first of these questions ("How can I iterate through Sheet 1.title"; Do you mean iterate through the column named title or iterate over the letters of the title of Sheet 1? Is "X" found in the title or another column (It makes it sound like "X" is in the title but your diagram is different).

It's also too broad because you're working with too much information. If the part you're stuck on is looking things up by title and filling out the database, you could do this question with just 3 columns and two sheets instead of providing all the information. Taking the time to break the problem down into the most simple form shows respect for the people who are volunteering their time to answer your question. It's the "minimal" in [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

---

I don't have enough time at the moment to finish going over the rest of your answer, but if I have time later I'll add on.

Comment: You're a saviour for explaining pretty much everything about what is an ideal post. The time you spent already is appreciated.

Comment: I was one of the close voters. You've pretty much summed up my thoughts on the matter when I cast the close vote.

Answer (score 8):

<sub>Note that the below is essentially a summary of some of the comments made on the OP's post here, mostly between them and me</sub>

---

As one of the close voters, when your question was originally closed it was easily too broad, you'd made no attempt and just given a list of criteria for the thing that you wanted, we won't write code for you.

Now that it's been edited, the honest truth is that I'm not particularly interested in looking at it to review whether or not it warrants reopening based on your responses here (and on the question) today.

You said in the comments:

> I just thought my attempt wasn't worth posting, since it didn't work in the slightest. ... I'd also like to ask why my responses here today cause you not to even want to look at it

An attempt is always worth posting, regardless of how bad you consider it to be, people value effort, if they think you've made no effort why would they help?

As for why I won't look, I've seen the edits you made to the post ("too much hostility", "ganged up on", "without anyone telling me the problem"), you were explicitly told the problem in the close banner as mentioned in the comments:

> You cannot claim that apparently nobody told you, because 5 users told you by closing the question, which puts a banner saying "Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question. If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit the question."

You were in no way ganged up on, lots of peoples questions get closed, some get downvoted into the ground, closing is just one way we moderate content, we don't do it as an insult or an attack.

You need to understand that we get dozens (hundreds even) of awful questions every day, we can't walk everyone through writing their questions because we don't have the time. I can't comment on your competence being insulted or elitism because I can't see the comments that were deleted, but your list of issues mentioned here appear as a *"woe is me, reopen my question"*.

We won't reopen your question based on *what has happened to you*, we'll reopen it based on *the merits of the question itself*, but moaning doesn't encourage others to help.